# How to delete specific entries from a table using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Program {
 static void Main(string[] args) {
     pricingdemoEntities demo = new pricingdemoEntities();
     var output = (from result in demo.demotables where 
                   result.value == "array"
         select result).ToList();
     output.RemoveAll(x = > x.value == "array");
     demo.SaveChanges();
 }
```

I want to delete all entries in my table where `value = "array"` using linq alone.
I tried it in the above way. The values get deleted in the list but are not updated to the table.
Please suggest solution to this .![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems, you filtered for "array", so the removeAll should remove everything. I know this does not answer your question. Just confused why its like this.

Comment: Your code is actually clearing the list of results in memory, not the records in your table. In other words, you're calling the RemoveAll method of the List<T> class (which has no effect on the database), and not the Remove method of the DbSet class (which instructs ADO to call the SQL DELETE command on the next SaveChanges()).

Comment: I know that I am deleting from the list and not from the db. In order to delete it from db do I need to add any assembly reference?

Answer (score 2):

You are not removing them from your `DB`, what you are doing is to modify the `output` list which has nothing to do with your db context.

```
foreach(var entry in output)
   demo.demotables.Remove(entry);

demo.SaveChanges();
```

In addition to that you should use a using statement to dispose your `DbContext`.

```
using(var demo = new pricingdemoEntities())
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I tried it but I am getting an exception.Db update exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just skip the `otuput` variable:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        pricingdemoEntities demo = new pricingdemoEntities();
        demo.demotables.RemoveAll(x => x.value == "array");
        demo.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```